# How to find the value of integer k efficiently for which q divides b ^ k finitely?

Tags: division, integer-division, greatest-common-divisor

We have given two integers b and q, and we want to find the minimum value of an integer 'k' for which q completely divides b^k or k does not exist. Can we find out the value of k efficiently? Not just iterating each value of k (0, 1, 2, 3, ...) and checking (b^k) % q == 0) where q <= k or q >= k.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution-
If q divides **pow(b,k)** then all prime factors of **q** are prime factors of **b**. Now we can do iterations **q = q ÷ gcd(b,q)** while **gcd(q,b)≠1**. If **q≠1** after iterations, there are prime factors of **q** which are not prime factors of **b** 
then 
**k doesn't exist** 
else
 **k = no of iteration**.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, k will never equal zero unless q=1.  k will never equal one unless q=b.

Next, if you can factorize q and b, then you can reason about them.

If there are any prime factors of b that are not factors of q at all, then k does not exist.  Otherwise, k has to be large enough so that every factor of b^k is represented in q.

Here's some pseudo-code:

```
if (q==1) return 0;
if (q==b) return 1;
// qfactors and bfactors are arrays, one element per factor
let qfactors = prime_factorization(q);
let bfactors = prime_factorization(b);
let kmin=0;
foreach (f in bfactors.unique) {
     let bcount = bfactors.count(f);
     let qcount = qfactors.count(f);
     if (qcount==0 || qcount < bcount) return -1; // k does not exist
     kmin_f = ceiling(bcount/qcount);
     if (kmin_f > kmin) let kmin = kmin_f;
}
return kmin;
```

Comment: Your solution is fine, but I think it will face issues in prime factorization for the larger values of b or q.

Answer (score 0):

If q = 1 ; k = 0

If b = q ; k = 1

If b > q and factors ; k = 1

If b < q and factors ; k != I

If b != q and not factors ; k != I

We know,
Dividend = Divisor x Quotient + Reminder

=> Dividend = Divisor x Quotient  [Here, Reminder = 0]

Now go for calculation of Maxima and Minima as lower the value of Quotient is lower the value of 'k'.

If you consider the Quotient as 1 (lowest but spl case) then your formula for 'k' becomes,

k = log q/log b